# hitTestObject outputs more than once?

Tags: actionscript-3, action

```
public class GameEnter extends MovieClip
{


  public function GameEnter()
  {
    addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, shootBullet);
  }
    public var _bullet1:bullet = new bullet;
    public var angleRadian = Math.atan2(mouseY - 300,mouseX - 300);
    public var angleDegree = angleRadian * 180 / Math.PI;


    public function shootBullet(evt:MouseEvent)
    {
        _bullet1.x = 300;
        _bullet1.y = 300;
        _bullet1.angleRadian = Math.atan2(mouseY - 300,mouseX -300);
        _bullet1.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, bulletEnterFrame);
        addChild(_bullet1);
    }


    public var speed1:int = 10;
    public function bulletEnterFrame(evt:Event) 
    {
        _bullet1.x += Math.cos(_bullet1.angleRadian) * speed1;
        _bullet1.y += Math.sin(_bullet1.angleRadian) * speed1;
        _bullet1.rotation = _bullet1.angleRadian*180/Math.PI;
        checkHit();
        if (_bullet1.x < 0 || _bullet1.x > 600 || _bullet1.y < 0 || _bullet1.y > 600) 
        {
            removeChild(_bullet1);
            _bullet1.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, bulletEnterFrame);
        }
    }



public function checkHit()
{
     if(_bullet.hitTestObject(enemy))
     {
          trace("Enemy hit");
     }
}

}
```

}
Essentially what happens is it prints out "Enemy hit" about 10 times. I'm wondering: How would I make it only trace "Enemy hit" once? 
I think the problem is that for every frame that the bullet is on the enemy, it prints it out, how do I fix that to only print out once?

I will eventually replace "trace("Enemy hit");" with a function or something.

Answer (score 0):

checkHit() is called on every frame and the bullet is only being removed when its outside the game area? This means "enemy hit" will be traced every frame the checkHit() is true. Once the hit occurs you should remove the event listener similarly to when the bullet moves off the screen.